# nav2: changing controller plugins manually during runtime

Tags: microcontroller, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a controller plugin by following the [tutorial](https://navigation.ros.org/plugin_tutorials/docs/writing_new_nav2controller_plugin.html)  and it is working as expected. I now have two controller plugins (The DWB controller present by default and the controller plugin I created) which are loaded at runtime and I can use those plugins in my behaviour tree as per my requirements.

My question is:
Is there a way in which I can I change the controller plugin during **runtime manually** if the need arises? If yes then How?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with ROS2 Foxy

Thanks for the help in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366323/nav2:-changing-controller-plugins-manually-during-runtime/) by [Divyanshu](https://answers.ros.org/users/63683/divyanshu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2020-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Nav2, you can have `N` different plugins in the controller server, rather than just 1. So you can load both of your plugins to use in the controller server and have them individually callable by their "name" namespace using the BT nodes for follow path. There's a `controller_id` field that defaults to the default ID we assign in the controller server, but that can be set to a different value in the section of the behavior tree that requires another controller.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2020-12-17**:
Is there any tutorial or sample package from which one can learn? Specifically for beginners of Nav2.